# Optimize a MYSQL query while loop output with a for loop combination PHP

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to output each row from a mysql query slightly differently in terms of styling, however I want to try to avoid having to use offsets and multiple queries.

Current code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$title = $row["title"];
// output first news item with a style
echo '<div class="style-1">'.$title.'</div>';
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$title = $row["title"];
// output second news item with different style
echo '<div class="style-2">'.$title.'</div>';
}
```

I would thus like to avoid having 2 (or more) queries simple because I want to use different css classes for each while row, something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
$title = $row["title"];
} // end while
$i = 1;
for($i; $i<2; $i++){ // output first row item with first style
echo '<div class="style-1">'.$title.'</div>';
} // end for loop 1
for($i; $i<3; $i++){ // output first row item with second style
echo '<div class="style-2">'.$title.'</div>';
} // end for loop 2
for($i; $i<4; $i++){ // output third row item with third style
echo '<div class="style-3">'.$title.'</div>';
} // end for loop 3
    ...
```

Desired Output:

```
<div class="style-1">News Headline Title 1</div>
<div class="style-2">News Headline Title 2</div>
<div class="style-3">News Headline Title 3</div>
...
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the table structure and also with what should be the desired output ?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "table structure"? the desired output is written above: echo '<div class="style-1">'.$title.'</div>';

Comment: What should be the desired output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want 3 different styles, and here's how I would accomplish this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10";
$query = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

$i = 1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $title = $row["title"];
    if($i<2){
        $styleNumber = 1;
    }
    else if($i<3){
        $styleNumber = 2;
    }
    else if($i<4){
        $styleNumber = 3;
    }
    echo '<div class="style-'.$styleNumber.'">'.$title.'</div>';
    $i++;
} 
// end while
```

**Output**:
Title 1 (Style 1)
Title 2 (Style 2)
Title 3 (Style 3)
Title 4 (Style 3)

Comment: I think you need to add the part where you increment `$i` inside the while loop.

Comment: Ah yes, I have since added it in

Comment: awesome! works really sweet! thank you for your help and solution!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer. Just a comment/improvement of @JonTan answer  since it was chosen as correct one.

My guess is that OP need to loop styles for every 3 records, but not to set style only for 3 first returned.

That means we can change condition from `if($i<3){`, `if($i<2){` to something like:

```
$i = 1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    $title = $row["title"];
    if($i % 3 == 0){
        $styleNumber = 3;
    } else if($i % 2 == 0){
        $styleNumber = 2;
    } else {
        $styleNumber = 1;
    }
    echo '<div class="style-'.$styleNumber.'">'.$title.'</div>';
    $i++;
}
```